# Добавить по условию Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста есть компонент кнопки у него есть пропс `disabled` который делает ее неактивной, как добавить его по условию ? `v-if="{showEditBranch: disabled}"` так не работает

```
<b-button>Small Button</b-button>

data() {
   return {
     showEditBranch: true
   }
}
```

Comment: `v-if="showEditBranch"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, речь идет о компоненте Button (BootstrapVue, [документация](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/button#disabled-state))

Рассмотрим пример из документации:

```
<b-button disabled size="lg" variant="primary">Disabled</b-button>
```

В данном примере prop disabled отвечает за то, будет ли иметь кнопка свойство disabled. Исходя из [документации Vue по передаче входных параметров](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), компонент из примера имеет props disabled в значении true. В prop disabled можно передать переменную из data() так:

```
<b-button :disabled="variable" size="lg" variant="primary">Disabled</b-button>
```

где variable - переменная из data()

для приведенного вами кода:

```
<b-button :disabled="showEditBranch">Small Button</b-button>

data() {
   return {
     showEditBranch: true
   }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ выше описывает ваш кейс, но добавлю еще один комментарий, такое использование `v-if="{showEditBranch: disabled}"` всегда будет давать `true`, потому что в данном случае директива `v-if` будет воспринимать `{showEditBranch: disabled}` как простой объект и будет приводить его к значению типа `boolean` (приведение объектов в js дает `true`).